# asp.net MVC3 show query result on details page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC3

DB has a table called users (id,name,username,lat,lon).  I do not have access to the database.

I created entity model using the above table. Then, I created a SearchController and Search View. On the index page I display the list of all users.  Also, I created a form on the page that searches the table using the username. After clicking on the details link I show the details page where I display the user's details.

Now I need to display other users that are within a mile of the selected user. I already have the sql query to get the list of other users that are within a mile of the selected user (This is a sql query). I need to show this list on Details page.

I created a custom class model.

```
public class SearchDetailsViewModel
{
    public decimal id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> lat { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> lon { get; set; }
    public string profile_img_url { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<user> usersWithinAMile { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach. Also, I do not know how I would intialize this class.

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: How are you doing queries if you don't have access to the database?

Comment: i have the connection string. so i can query the database. i just don't have the rights to create views and stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track, you get the data from your SQL into the class, and then to the view, in the ActionResult, like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public ActionResult Index() {
    var data = new List<SearchDetailsViewModel>();
    // foreach row in your SQL
    var s = new SearchDetailsViewModel();
    s.lat = -42.00000M;
    // more data added to the s object here
    data.Add(s);
    // end loop

    return View("ThePage", data);
}
```

Then on your view itself you would do something like this:

```
@foreach (var s in Model) {
    // output your values on the page
}
```